# How to make Django ORM query database through reverse ForeignKey work faster?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, orm

I have 3 models connected with ForeignKey:

```
class Product(TimeStampedModel):    
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, )
    shop = models.ForeignKey('Shop', related_name='products', to_field='shop_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    brand = models.ForeignKey('Brand', related_name='products', to_field='brand_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        indexes = [                
            models.Index(fields=['title', 'shop', 'sale']),
            models.Index(fields=['shop', 'brand', 'price', 'title']), ]
```

```
class Brand(models.Model):    
    brand_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,)
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
```

```
class Shop(models.Model):
    shop_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True,)
    shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=False, null=False, db_index=True)
```

From my view I try to filter Brands where available for this Shop, accessing Shop via Product ForeignKey:

```
brands = Brand.objects.filter(products__shop__shop_name=shop).distinct('brand_name').order_by('brand_name')
```

The problem is that this query takes a long time to process: from 1-3+ seconds. Is there a way to make it work faster? 
May be I can add some Indexes? I have already tried some combinations (you can find them in `Product - Meta class`), but it seems like that doesn't help.
`select_related('product')` - throws an error: `Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'product'. Choices are: (none)`
Or may be there is a better way when I create a Brand entry - add a some kind `available_in_shops = ListField(...)`(I have found this can be made with JSONField, but I don't know yet how this works exactly)? And store there a list of shops where that Brand is available?

Comment: explore select_related (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related).

Comment: I have just edited, that I have also tried that :)

Comment: One other thing you can try. Add a direct many2many relation between brands and shops. Update this relation post_save whenever a product-shop relation is added/modified/deleted. You can use the m2m field to filter faster

Comment: does that mean that reversing access ForeignKey is always bad idea if there are more then few objects to access? And what did you mean in "Update this relation post_save"?

Comment: Generally, try to avoid multiple database hits for one query. 'post_save, post_delete', these are signals triggered when model is saved or deleted respectively. Explore django signals.